# Create Facebook Campaign and Ad Sets using the Facebook API without the permission error

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using the Graph API provided by Facebook to create an advert. I have done the following:

1- `FB.Login()` from my webpage with the respective permissions ,i.e, `{ scope: 'publish_pages, manage_pages, publish_actions,ads_management'}`

2- Used `me/accounts` node to get to the appropriate Facebook page out of pages owned by me and then asked for its `access_token`.

3- Finally I have used the node `/<advertname>/campaigns` with `POST` to create the advert. The response returned is `[object Object]`

I have tried the same using the `Graph Explorer` : [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) after adding the adaccount in the app settings as mentioned in some of the SO answers and Fb developer guide. 
[image: Screenshot]

But it still returns the same error `"message": "(#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings -> advanced ->...`

Here is how I have asked for the permissions at Login:

```
      FB.login(function(){
// used to get user accessToken
 var pageId = '1928652150728161'; // facebook page id from page info
 var authResp = FB.getAuthResponse();
 var postdesc= "Random Link";
 var jla="So this is it www.facebook.com/2394298374923874928";

 }, { scope: 'publish_pages, manage_pages, publish_actions,ads_management' });
```

Here is the code that I am using to create the advert:

```
   $("#createAd").click(function(){

                    var advertname;
                    if($("#advertname").val()==""|| $("#advertname").length==0)
                {
                        var timeStampInMs = window.performance && window.performance.now && window.performance.timing && window.performance.timing.navigationStart ? window.performance.now() + window.performance.timing.navigationStart : Date.now();
                        advertname=timeStampInMs+"CustomAdvert";
                }
                else
                        advertname=$("#advertname").val();
                        var idval="myPageid";
                        alert(advertname);
                        //POST /act_XXXXXXXX/campaigns
                var auth = FB.getAuthResponse();


                //make a function call for same later 

                FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get', {access_token : auth.accessToken}, function(response){
                    console.log(response); // this is returning an object with the accounts
                    FB.api('/me/permissions', 'get', {access_token : pageAccessToken}, function(resp){console.log(resp)});


                              // find the page access token for the page we want to admin
                              var pageAccessToken = ''; 
                              for(i in response.data){
                                if(response.data[i].id == idval) {
                                    console.log("here it is bruh" +response.data[i]);
                                    pageAccessToken = response.data[i].access_token;


                                  // do the actual post now
                                  FB.api('/my_adaccountid/campaigns', 'post', {
                                    name: advertname,
                                    objective:"LINK_CLICKS"
                                  }, function(info){
                        console.log(info);// error 100 OAuth

                                  });

                                }
                              }
                    });


            });
```

Is there something I am missing. How can I create this campaign so that later on I could create an adSet for it to start delivering.

Comment: _“The response returned is [object Object]”_ - that’s because you are forcing it to be cast into a string, by concatenating it with other stuff. Don’t do that, output the object directly, so that you can expect it on console.

Comment: Have you actually done what the error message says still needs doing?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked in console with the string concatenation.  The error shown is error: code:100 type:OAuthException

Comment: At what specific point in the script? Most likely a permission or token issue. Permissions are _not_ asked for via FB.api, I don’t know what makes people regularly get that idea.

Comment: I already have posted as a Page with the permissions,i.e., by asking for the access_token of the related page which required `{ scope: 'publish_pages, manage_pages, publish_actions,ads_management'}` where publish_pages was needed for publishing/posting as a page. However this time I need to create an Advert which also needs ads_management, which I have already provided in that `scope`. The Error appears right after I call the POST for the advert
`FB.api('/my_adaccountid/campaigns', 'post', { name: advertname, objective:"LINK_CLICKS"}, function(info){console.log(info); //error thrown`

Comment: _“which also needs ads_management, which I have already provided in that `scope`”_ - in _what_ scope? Again: Passing a scope to FB.api makes no sense at all, that is not how you ask for permissions.

Comment: And your screenshot from Graph API Explorer suggests that you are using that with the Graph API Explorer _app id_ - which you for sure will _not_ have added your ad account to. You might want to start by selecting _your_ app from the dropdown in the upper right corner ...

Comment: `{ scope: 'publish_pages, manage_pages,publish_actions,ads_management'}` <= this scope. In my previous scenario I could not post as a Page until I added the Publish permission for page in the scope. It would not post as a page and would post on my behalf. I have additionally added the adaccount in my app's advanced settings. Kindly let me know if this is not the right way. Thanks for the insight

Comment: _“this scope”_ - _where_???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152042/discussion-between-rawatdeepesh-and-cbroe).